# Import error, can't find files error in stackblitz

Tags: reactjs, file, import, find, stackblitz

hi can anyone please help me to solve this error in stackblitz -react project.

Please click on the below mentioned link to replicate the scenario - https://stackblitz.com/github/bharathkumarrangarajj/front-end-dev-portfolio?file=src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FWorkcard.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FAboutcontent.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FPricingcard.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2Fwork.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FWorkcarddata.js

[image: error message screenshot]

and here is my source code link - [stackblitz project link](https://stackblitz.com/github/bharathkumarrangarajj/front-end-dev-portfolio?file=src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FWorkcard.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FAboutcontent.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FPricingcard.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2Fwork.js,src%2FRoutes%2FComponents%2FWorkcarddata.js)

i changed the path of the files as well from normal to relative path but still issue exists

Comment: Hi, I have shared the link of my project as well.. Please click on that link

Answer (score 0):

If you have put the PNG file into Github, you can right-click the picture in GitHub and select a new tab, and copy its URL instead of the relative position, and it can also be displayed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).